# JobQueue.run_repeating to run a function without command handler in Telegram

Tags: telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I need to start sending notifications to a TG group, before that I want to run a function continuosly which would query an API and store data in DB. While this function is running I would want to be able to send notifications if they are available in the DB:

That's my code:

```
import telegram
from telegram.ext import Updater,CommandHandler, JobQueue

token = "tokenno:token"

bot = telegram.Bot(token=token)

def start(update, context):
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id,
                             text="You will now receive msgs!")


def callback_minute(context):
    chat_id = context.job.context

    # Check in DB and send if new msgs exist
    send_msgs_tg(context, chat_id)


def callback_msgs():
    fetch_msgs()


def main():
    JobQueue.run_repeating(callback_msgs, interval=5, first=1, context=None)
    
    updater = Updater(token,use_context=True)
    dp = updater.dispatcher
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start",start, pass_job_queue=True))

    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This code gives me error:
TypeError: run_repeating() missing 1 required positional argument: 'callback'

Any help would greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code, let me try to point them out:

1.
`def callback_msgs(): fetch_msgs()`
You use `callback_msgs` as callback for your job. But job callbacks take exactly one argument of type `telegram.ext.CallbackContext`.

2. ```
    JobQueue.run_repeating(callback_msgs, interval=5, first=1, context=None)
   ```

   `JobQueue` is a class. To use `run_repeating`, which is an instance method, you'll need an instance of that class. In fact the `Updater` already builds an instance for you, it's available as `updater.job_queue` in your case. So the call should look like this:

   ```
   updater.job_queue.run_repating(callback_msgs, interval=5, first=1, context=None)
   ```
3. ```
   CommandHandler("start",start, pass_job_queue=True)
   ```

   This is not strictly speaking an issue, bot `pass_job_queue=True` has no effect at all, because you use `use_context=True`

Please note that there is a nice tutorial on `JobQueue` over at the [ptb-wiki](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Extensions-%E2%80%93-JobQueue). There is also an [example](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/tree/master/examples#timerbotpy) on how to use it.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`

Comment: That worked! Frankly speaking I'm more of a copy paste coder, just know the basics of Python, when it comes to coding async and class based stuff I falter :) Not getting time to read it properly! Using a class like an instance :D :D :D you know me ;)